# I can't send a transaction uses BitGo API

Tags: transactions, blockchain, bitgo

I have a test BitGo account, and there are test wallets. One of this wallet has 1.1000 TBTC (test btc). I want to send transaction uses BitGo API.

***I do this request:***

http://localhost:3080/api/v2/tbtc/wallet/"my_wallet_id"/sendcoins

with this headers:
`Content-Type application/json
Authorization Bearer "my_token"`

and this body:

`{
    "address":"address_where_i_send",
    "amount":0.1,
    "walletPassphrase":"my_test_passphrase"
}`

and I get **this response**:

`{
    "error": "sub-dust-threshold amount for 2N4ebmhA3FDuPiULXUEu1jBdPc3y2hk1NrD: 0.5",
    "message": "sub-dust-threshold amount for 2N4ebmhA3FDuPiULXUEu1jBdPc3y2hk1NrD: 0.5"
}`

***Can somebody explain why I have this response, and how fix it?***
(I have V2 BTC wallet)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to BitGo Documentation:

> amount    number  Yes Amount to be sent (in Satoshis), e.g. 0.1 * 1e8 for
>   a tenth of a Bitcoin

https://bitgo.github.io/bitgo-docs/#send-coins-to-address

So, the amount should be passed as `0.1 * 1e8` = `10000000`